# Use data from funtion inside another function | Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have and array that came from an Api Post call, storaged into `$valores` on `getApi()`, i just need to access that array from my views to display the data

```
public function getApi(){
  $valores = $this->input->post('data');
  // print_r($valores); <--- with this i see the array in my console.log
    return $valores;
}

public function index()
    {

    // includes
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('includes/footer', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['api'] = $this->getApi(); <-- i want to render this on my view

    // Menu

    $data['menuProfile'] = $this->load->view('app/menuProfile', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['sidebarMenu'] = $this->load->view('app/sidebarMenu', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['topNavigation'] = $this->load->view('app/topNavigation', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['menuFooter'] = $this->load->view('app/menuFooter', NULL, TRUE);

    // Dashboard

    $dashboard['dinp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dinp', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['dispTitle'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dispTitle', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['porcentaje'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/porcentaje', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['temp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/temp', NULL, TRUE);
    $dashboard['velocity'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/velocity', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dashboard', $dashboard, TRUE);


    $this->load->view('includes/head');
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/jquery');
    }
```

and this is how i thought that i can display the data in my view

```
<div class="right_col" role="main" id="Dashboard">
  <div class="">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="x_panel">
            <?=$dispTitle?>
            <div class="x_content">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 widget widget_tally_box">
              <?=$api?>            <--- just doesn't display anything, i think its empty or null
              <!-- percent -->
              <?=$porcentaje?>
              <!-- dinp -->
              <?=$dinp?>
              <!-- dinp -->
              <?=$dinp?>
              <!-- temp -->
              <?=$temp?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you say that your `getApi()` method returns an array? You can't really `echo` an array.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah, i just was testing some things, my original code its 
`<?php print_r($api) ?>`, but pritns `null`

Comment: Sounds like `getApi()` must be returning `null`, then. Once you figure out why that happens, you'll need to loop over `$api` if it's an array and `echo` the items within it, rather than just `echo $api;`

Answer (score -1):

U r passing $data to the view page but u saved api return data in

```
$dashboard['api']
```

try to change this to

```
$data['api']
```